# No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so'

Tags: 16.04, cmake

I am building a cmake project in C++ on ubuntu 16.04.

I get this error when I build my project :

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so', needed by bin/worker
```

The problem is this file does not exist on my system :

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so': No such file or directory
```

I searched for ways I could have this file and what to install.
But nothing solves the problem.

Any suggestions what could be the problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `libegl1-mesa-dev` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libEGL.so&sort_by=pkg). You will need it to compile anything which links to Mesa's EGL.